# Drawable resource not renaming in Recource Manager so I cannot run my app

Tags: android-studio

I am working on a homework assignment. The professor gave us files and said "drag and drop in your drawables folder". I did so and began working away. When I went to try to test the app the first time, it was mad because quite a few of the drawable files he gave us had uppercase letters in them (ex: cheeseBurger), even though I wasn't even using them yet. So I just went through and renamed every file that had an uppercase which worked fine. It wasn't until a few hours later, when I started actually using some of those files that when I went to test the app again, it gave me the same error. If I look in the physical drawables folder, it shows my changes (from cheeseBurger to cheeseburger, etc.) but if I look in the Resource Manager folder, it is still showing as it was (cheeseBurger). I cannot find a way to change the name in the Resource Manager.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZGoW.png)  is a pic of the Resource Manager and
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAW5G.png) is a pic of the drawable folder files

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding, and simply restarting Android Studio with no success.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Open Drawable folder in `Explorer` and rename it from there.

[image]

#### if the problem still persists, try `Invalidating caches and Restart` with all options to be checked.

[image]

Comment: Invalidating caches worked! Thank you so much!